# Quality initiative: make downvotes count as much as upvotes

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, voting, upvotes

Downvoting a question removes 2 rep, while upvoting a question grants 5 rep. Downvoting an answer costs 1 rep and removes 2 rep, while upvoting an answer grants 10 rep. This heavily skews voting results toward the positive side, as the cost difference encourages voters to upvote instead of downvote and the rep granted encourages answerers to persevere with low-quality answers until the downvotes outweigh the upvotes by a whopping 5:1. SO is a huge site with lots of content, but so much of it is bad that even searching is sometimes fruitless (to say nothing of browsing). Adding a 1-rep cost to upvotes (think of them as tiny, adorable bounties) and boosting the downvote rep impact to match that of upvotes would empower SO to much more effectively discourage low-quality content and indicate high-quality content.

[image: doesn't matter got reps]

Comment: I hate getting punished when downvoting a terrible answer, just trying to keep a minimal level of answers and loosing 1 rep for that. But this suggestion is just like the reputation feast on the first days of the public documentation beta. It was disgusting

Comment: Would question upvotes remain free?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom - [I don't know.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7BkdARYNAE)

Answer (score 9):

There's this thing called [loss aversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion), which basically boils down to: people don't like losing stuff. This is especially so when said people feel like they "worked" for whatever it is that they are losing.

> Some studies have suggested that losses are twice as powerful, psychologically, as gains.
>   <sup>(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion)</sup>

The Powers That Be want people to continue participating, and will do everything they can (within reason) to keep people participating. One way they do this is to minimize the losses and maximize the gains *felt* by those participating.

After all, if you're voting on the content (not the user), why do you care about how your voting affects the user? I personally only care about how my voting affects the score of the content I'm voting on.

We vote on things to bring the best questions and answers to the top, and push the worst questions and answers to the bottom; not to punish or reward people. Punishments and rewards just side effects of the voting system.

Comment: If people are rewarded for bad content, they'll keep posting it. SO is big enough to no longer need to make people feel good about posting any content at all.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 if it is truly bad content, the system takes care of that.

Comment: Sometimes. But often not.

Comment: You're quite right that loss aversion is a very powerful psychological force.  This force results in lots of people not downvoting content that they feel is bad because they're so averse to losing the 1 rep for the downvote.  This causes bad content to not be identified as such.

Comment: @Ðаn No the gamification system is designed to get people participating and keep people participating. Downvotes and upvotes are for scoring and sorting content. The fact that upvotes cause users to gain rep is to keep users participating. The fact that downvotes cause users to lose rep is to signal to them that the content they have created may need work, and to give users downvoting the feeling that their downvotes actually do something to signal the users that their content may need work.